# How to select columns containing different text combination from data frame?

Tags: r

I have example data like below but my real data contains more than 10000 rows

```
IND  snp1      snp2    snp3     snp4    snp5
1    A/G       T/T     T/C      G/C     G/G
2    A/A       C/C     G/G      G/G     A/A
3    T/T       G/G     C/C      C/C     T/T
```

Now i want to subset only columns having these characters `(A/T,A/G,A/C,T/A,T/G,T/C,G/A,G/T,G/C,C/A,C/T,C/G)` after following the above condition I should subset `snp1`, `snp3` and `snp4` and I will get them by using this code

```
select(df, snp1, snp3, snp4)[1, 1:3]
```

this can happen with small number of columns but in my case I need to go through all 10000 columns for characters and subset them to different file. How can i do this in R is `tidyverse` package will be helpful for me or not? if yes please let me know how it will be. any help in this regard will be highly appreciated
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ***tidy selection*** in `select()`.

```
library(dplyr)
cond <- c("A/T", "A/G", "A/C", "T/A", "T/G", "T/C", "G/A", "G/T", "G/C", "C/A", "C/T", "C/G")

df %>%
  select(starts_with("snp") & where(~ any(.x %in% cond)))

#   snp1 snp3 snp4
# 1  A/G  T/C  G/C
# 2  A/A  G/G  G/G
# 3  T/T  C/C  C/C
```

---

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(IND = 1:3, snp1 = c("A/G", "A/A", "T/T"), snp2 = c("T/T", 
"C/C", "G/G"), snp3 = c("T/C", "G/G", "C/C"), snp4 = c("G/C", "G/G", "C/C"),
snp5 = c("G/G", "A/A", "T/T")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: DarrenTsait thanks lot for your help, yes its working perfectly.